# What I am doing wrong when parsing an ISO8601 date time?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, assert, iso8601

I am expecting the test below to pass. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? Most likely I am using a wrong pattern but I can't see what is wrong.

```
@Test
public void parseDateTest() {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss'Z'");
    DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime("1983-03-06T05:00:03.000Z");
    assertEquals("1983-03-06T05:00:03.000Z", dt.toString());
}
```

FYI dt.toString() does print: 1983-03-06T05:00:00.000Z

Thanks!

P.S.
Please note that on this snippet I rely on the default timezone. This is not production code and how to handle correctly the timezone based on needs is covered by many other questions.

*The default time zone is derived from the system property user.timezone. If that is null or is not a valid identifier, then the value of the JDK TimeZone default is converted. If that fails, UTC is used.*

Comment: FYI I am using Joda DateTime in this snippet.

Comment: Rather than post additional information as comments, edit the Question. If using a web browser, look for the `edit` link below the Question, to the lower-left.

Comment: By the way, no need for the formatter. The default format of the `toString` method on `DateTime` is the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard format being attempted in this Question: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZ`. Pass string to constructor of DateTime: `new DateTime( "1983-03-06T05:00:03.000Z" )`. I would also pass a desired time zone to assign rather than rely implicitly on JVM's current default time zone: `new DateTime( "1983-03-06T05:00:03.000Z", DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/London" ) )`.

Comment: Thanks @BasilBourque. The snipped is only an example used to explain my problem. The real context is more complex and do need an explicit formatter. Why you say I am relying on the JVM timezone? I am using Z which is perfectly fine to me. Please see this [doc](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/iso-time.html#zone)

Comment: (a)Again, you are posting additional info as comments rather than editing your Question. If your question is about specific formats, say so in your Question! (b) Nothing in your code is about regex, so your first sentence is confusing. (c) The topic of parsing strings with Joda-Time has been covered in *hundreds* of answers. *Please search before posting.* Those answers already explain that a `DateTime` knows its own assigned time zone and if not specified the JVM’s current default time zone is assigned. The `Z` on the end is an offset, a time zone is much more than an offset.

Comment: a) b) c) Thanks @Basil, I see your point. I did edit the question trying to make it more clear.

Answer (score 4):

This checks to see if `"1983-03-06T05:00:03.000Z"` is equal to `dt.toString()`. You say that `dt.toString()` is equal to `"1983-03-06T05:00:00.000Z"`.

```
"1983-03-06T05:00:03.000Z" !== "1983-03-06T05:00:00.000Z"
```

Now the problem is why `dt.toString()` does not have the correct amount of seconds. Let's look at your `DateTimeFormat` pattern:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.sss'Z'"
```

[According to the docs](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html#forPattern(java.lang.String)), `s` is for "second of minute" and `S` is for "fraction of second" (note the case). This means in your input string, both `03` and `000` are being parsed as seconds (when the later should be fractions) and your `DateTime`'s seconds are being overridden with `00`.  Try updating this format string:

```
@Test
public void parseDateTest() {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
    DateTime dt = formatter.parseDateTime("1983-03-06T05:00:03.000Z");
    assertEquals("1983-03-06T05:00:03.000Z", dt.toString());
}
```

Comment: I assumed that the fact that "1983-03-06T05:00:03.000Z" should be equal to ds.String() was clear by the context, but thanks for your clarification. Anyway your answer is correct!

Comment: @ChristianSisti I assumed you knew, but wasn't entirely sure so thought it would help. Glad `SSS` solved the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

### java.time

Quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time` API**: `java.time` API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and therefore you do not need a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse a date-time string which is already in ISO 8601 format (e.g. your date-time string, `1983-03-06T05:00:03.000Z`).

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strModifiedDate = "1983-03-06T05:00:03.000Z";
        Instant instant = Instant.parse(strModifiedDate);
        System.out.println(instant);

        // It can also be directly parsed into a ZonedDateTime
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(strModifiedDate);
        System.out.println(zdt);

        // or even into an OffsetDateTime
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strModifiedDate);
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
1983-03-06T05:00:03Z
1983-03-06T05:00:03Z
1983-03-06T05:00:03Z
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `dt.toString()`, use `formatter.format(dt)` instead. That's what the formatter is for:

```
@Test
public void parseDateTest() {
  DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
  LocalDateTime dt = formatter.parse("1983-03-06T05:00:03.000Z", LocalDateTime::from);
  assertEquals("1983-03-06T05:00:03.000Z", formatter.format(dt));
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this works with Java8 I think? Yes I could have passed the formatter to the toString methods dt.toString(formatter), but this is anyway the default behavior of the Joda .toString().

Anyway you make me note I didn't specify I was using Joda, will update the question.

Comment: I saw Joda, but too late, and assuming the functionality was identical to Java 8 posted the answer anyway. Interestingly, the default behaviour of LocalDateTime dt.toString in Java 8 is `1983-03-06T05:00:03`. I didn't know about this difference, either.

Comment: To clarify, the default format used by the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) implementation of `toString` is the standard [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format: `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZZ` per [the doc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractDateTime.html#toString()). So this answer is incorrect or misleading, as there is no reason in this case to bother with a formatter.